# Insert record in many-to-many when key is DatabaseGeneratedOption.None

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I have two tables with many-to-many relation: 
***Employee***

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id{ get; set; }
  public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeLastName{ get; set; }
  .....
  public ICollection<EmployeeSupplier> EmployeeSuppliers { get; set; }
}
```

***Supplier***

```
public class Supplier
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public int Id{ get; set; }
  public string SupplierFirstName{ get; set; }
  public string SupplierLastName{ get; set; }
  .....
  public ICollection<EmployeeSupplier> EmployeeSuppliers { get; set; }
}
```

The third model represent the table between Employee and Supplier
***EmployeeSupplier***

```
public class EmployeeSupplier
{
    public int EmployeesId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeesId")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public int SuppliersId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SuppliersId")]
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    //Extra fieleds
    .....
}
```

I create a new record of EmployeeSupplier like this:

```
 var employeeSupplier = new EmployeeSupplier
            {
                Employee = new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeFirstName= "test",
                    EmployeeLastName = "test"
                    .....
                },
                Supplier = new Supplier
                {
                    Id = 123456, // I have to assign the value here from another source
                    SupplierFirstName= "test",
                    SupplierLastName = "test"
                },
                SuppliersId= 123456
            };
```

Then call the `api`:

```
await HttpClient.CreateJsonAsync("/api/EmployeeSuppliers", employeeSupplier);
```

***Error***:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EmployeeSuppliers_Suppliers_SuppliersId". The conflict occurred in database "TestDatabase", table "dbo.Suppliers", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

***My questions***

1. How can I create a record in  `EmployeeSupplier` table and in the same time create a new item in `Employee` table and `Supplier` table?
2. Is  `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` in `Supplier` table related with this error?.
3. If `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` doesn't relate with this error then why I didn't get the same error in FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_EmployeeSuppliers_Employees_EmployeesId`

Comment: What happens if you don't set the `SuppliersId` in the `EmployeeSupplier` but only in the `Supplier`?

Comment: The same error :)

Comment: First create both of your objects. Add both of the objects to their appropriate tables. Save the result of the .Add() method when you are adding an Employee. This is so you can get access to the auto generated id. SAVE THE CHANGES TO THE DB. This will make sure that both objects are stored in the db. Now that they exist in the db, you can create a new  EmployeeSupplier, by just inserting EmployeesId (that you saved in a variable) and SuppliersId (that you get from another source). Save db changes again and you are done. Hope it helps.

Comment: As for the error you are getting, that is because a supplier with this Id ->123456, already exists.